# For each level of factor aggregate values over all levels except the current one

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table, plyr

For each level of factor I need to extract values aggregated over all subsets of data.frame except the current one. For example, there is a several subjects doing a reaction time task during several days, and I need to compute mean reaction time for all subjects and all days, but not including the subject for whom the mean is computed. Currently, I do it like this:

```
 library(lme4)
 ddply(sleepstudy, .(Subject, Days), summarise, 
       avg_rt = mean(sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject != Subject &
                   sleepstudy$Days == Days,"Reaction"]), .progress="text")
```

It works fine for small data sets, but for large ones it can be very slow. Is there a way to do it faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#create big dataset
n <- 1e4
set.seed(1)
sleepstudy <- data.frame(Reaction=rnorm(n),Subject=1:4,Days=sort(rep((1:(n/4)),4)))


library(plyr)
system.time(
  res <- ddply(sleepstudy, .(Subject, Days), summarise, 
               avg_rt = mean(sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject != Subject &
                 sleepstudy$Days == Days,"Reaction"]))
)
#User      System      elapsed 
#6.532       0.013       6.556  

#use data.table for big datasets
library(data.table)

dt<- as.data.table(sleepstudy)
system.time(
 {dt[,avg_rt:=mean(Reaction),by=Days];
  dt[,n:=.N,by=Days];
  dt[,avg_rt:=(avg_rt*n-Reaction)/(n-1)]}
)
#User      System      elapsed 
#0.005       0.001       0.005 


#test if results are equal
dt2 <- as.data.table(res)
setkey(dt2,Subject,Days)
setkey(dt,Subject,Days)
all.equal(dt[,avg_rt],dt2[,avg_rt])
#[1] TRUE
```

For really large datasets the speed gain should be more pronounced. I just couldn't compare with larger datasets since `ddply` is so slow.

Comment: Thanks, it works great. Even if the same algorithm is used with ddply, data.table is still faster. It is also possible to control for multiple observations for each Subject X Days combination with something like: `dt[,sn:=.N,by=c("Subject","Days")];  dt[,s_avg_rt:=ifelse(sn==1,Reaction,.SD[,sum(Reaction)]),by=c("Subject","Days")];  dt[,avg_rt1:=(avg_rt*n-s_avg_rt)/(n-sn)];`

Comment: @Andrey Chetverikov I made a small change that improved performance considerably.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle Is it possible to do a "by not" with `data.table` like the `ddply` code is doing? Here it was possible to use simple algebra, but that might not always be the case (e.g., lets assume I want to use `lm` on all values except the current group).

Comment: @Roland A self join in `j` can be done, yes; e.g., `DT[,DT[.BY,...],by=...]`. The scoping can get a bit tricky (which `DT` do the by columns refer to inside which bit?), so `.BY` can be useful for that. Not join (`DT[-J(...)]`) isn't yet implemented, but long hand `DT[-DT[J(...),which=TRUE]` is still better than vector scanning `!=`. So, v ugly, but maybe `DT[,DT[-DT[.BY,which=TRUE]],by=...]`.  An aggregate step first is often much faster than joining from every group, though.

Comment: @Roland And `.I` might be useful for that too (when implemented); e.g., `DT[,DT[-.I],by=...]`.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle Thanks. `.I` seems very useful. Let's hope you can implement it soon.

Comment: @Roland Yes, I'd like `.I` too. The [19 outstanding bug reports](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=975&group_id=240&func=browse) come first unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's faster with `lapply` and `aggregate`:

```
do.call("rbind", (lapply(unique(sleepstudy$Subject),
                         function(x)
                           cbind(Subject = x,
                                 aggregate(Reaction ~ Days,
                                           subset(sleepstudy, Subject != x),
                                           mean)))))
```

**Update:**

I compared both commands with `system.time` and it appears the original is slower.

```
library(lme4)
library(plyr)

system.time(
ddply(sleepstudy, .(Subject, Days), summarise, 
      avg_rt = mean(sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject != Subject &
                    sleepstudy$Days == Days,"Reaction"]))
)

   # user  system elapsed 
   # 0.17    0.00    0.22 

system.time(
do.call("rbind", (lapply(unique(sleepstudy$Subject),
                         function(x) 
                           cbind(Subject = x,
                                 aggregate(Reaction ~ Days,
                                           subset(sleepstudy, Subject != x),
                                           mean)))))
)


   # user  system elapsed 
   # 0.12    0.00    0.12
```

Comment: For small data sets this works better than original, but on the big ones original is still better. http://pastebin.com/Zb4CaJrN

For 184320 rows its 6.041s for original and 10.96s for lapply and aggregate