# inverse selection for by in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
DT <- data.table(id=c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),condition=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),value=c(0,1,1,3,2,2))
```

For each value of `id` and `condition`, I want to compute the mean value for that condition but **for all values of id other than the current one**. My current solution is:

```
DT[,meanothers:=DT[id!=ID & condition==CONDITION,mean(value)],by=.(ID=id,CONDITION=condition)]
```

Is there a faster or more memory-efficient solution to this problem in data.table?

Comment: Preferably a faster one, but also understanding the idiom would be good

Comment: you can use `.BY` for slightly shorter code. `DT[,meanothers2:=DT[id!=.BY[1] & condition==.BY[2],mean(value)],by=.(id,condition)]`

Comment: Better in what sense? More concise, readable, faster, using less memory? Your solution is pretty clear but might be doing a lot of unnecssary work depending on the structure of your data.

Comment: The original dataset has tens of thousands of rows, so not massive, but it would help to improve the memory allocation and speed. Also, the number of by columns to iterate on is larger (imagine if there were 3 or 4 `condition` variables).

Comment: edited the 'better' to clarify

Answer (score 4):

Using the idea from [one of my old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660211/for-each-level-of-factor-aggregate-values-over-all-levels-except-the-current-one/12661162#12661162):

```
DT[, c("Sum", "N") := .(sum(value), .N), by = condition]
DT[, c("sum", "n") := .(sum(value), .N), by = .(id, condition)]
DT[, meanothers1 := (Sum - sum) / (N - n)]
#        id condition value meanothers   Sum     N   sum     n meanothers1
#    <char>     <num> <num>      <num> <num> <int> <num> <int>       <num>
# 1:      A         1     0        1.5     3     3     0     1         1.5
# 2:      A         2     1        2.5     6     3     1     1         2.5
# 3:      B         1     1        1.0     3     3     1     1         1.0
# 4:      B         2     3        1.5     6     3     3     1         1.5
# 5:      C         1     2        0.5     3     3     2     1         0.5
# 6:      C         2     2        2.0     6     3     2     1         2.0
```

Comment: this answer is definitely faster, however, it is limited to the function `mean`. Would it be possible to extend the approach to any other function?

Comment: You can use `DT[, meanothers2 := DT[-.I, mean(value), by = condition][["V1"]], by = id]` but I don't expect it to be fast for many IDs. The more specific the requirements the better the performance can be.

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id=c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),condition=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),value=c(0,1,1,3,2,2))

dt[, meanothers := mapply(
  FUN = function(x, y) weighted.mean(value, w = (x != id) * (y == condition)),
  x = id,
  y = condition
)][]
#>    id condition value meanothers
#> 1:  A         1     0        1.5
#> 2:  A         2     1        2.5
#> 3:  B         1     1        1.0
#> 4:  B         2     3        1.5
#> 5:  C         1     2        0.5
#> 6:  C         2     2        2.0
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>